# Unable to resolve why parent component re renders and the output is displayed twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested, react-router

Whenever i click the link component from Topics Component, Topics Component renders again so that the output is displayed twice. The Topics component is nested and have Link component to subtopics component.

the Topics component has link to '/topics/:topicId' and i tried using switch but it didn't resolve.

App component is

```
class App extends Component{
    render(){
      return(
       <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
               <Link to={'/'}>Home</Link>
               <Link to={'/topics'}>Topics</Link>
               <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home}/>
               <Route path='/topics' component={Topics}/>
           </div>     
        </BrowserRouter>
           );
           }   
         }
```

Topics Component

```
function Topics({match}){
    console.log("topics");
    return (
       <div>
         {topics.map(({name,id}) => (
           <li key={id}>
           <Link to={`${match.url}/${id}`}>{name}</Link>
           <Route exact path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
           </li>
       ))} 
       </div>
           );
}
```

Topic Component

```
function Topic({match}){
    const topic=topics.find(t=> 
    t.id===match.params.topicId;
    );
    return ( 
       <div>
         {topic.name}
       </div>
            );
    }
```

and the output when i click the link /topics is

[/topics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guZp4.png)

output when i click /topics/react-js

[/topics/react-js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esmYU.png)

as you can see react-js is displayed twice because /topics is again executed and then /topics/react-js.

Could Someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

First import "Switch" from react-router-dom.Then use it as

```
class App extends Component{
render(){
  return(
   <BrowserRouter>
      <div> 
         <Link to={'/'}>Home</Link>
         <Link to={'/topics'}>Topics</Link>
         <Switch>
           <Route exact path={'/'} component={Home}/>
           <Route path='/topics' component={Topics}/>
         </Switch>
       </div>     
    </BrowserRouter>
       );
       }   
     }
```

Comment: I had  tried using Switch but I'm not getting any output when I click the links.

Comment: See the link it may be helpfull https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-nested-routes/

Comment: Thanks it solved!! The Link component in Topics Component must be in an unorderd list while Route component must be after unorderd list.